# SUBSTR in informatica

Tags: informatica

What is the difference between SUBSTR(string,0,3) and SUBSTR(string,1,3) as both of them yield the same result.

For example:
If PHONE=809-555-444
SUBSTR(PHONE,0,3) = 809

And
SUBSTR(PHONE,1,3) = 809

Comment: Which languaje are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In informatica `SUBSTR`, first argument 0 or 1 - mean same thing - start from first character. ANy other +ve or -ve argument will be calculated from the beginning or the end.
Infa syntax -

```
SUBSTR( string, start [,length] )
```

Basically, informatica borrowed the logic form Oracle. Oracle `SUBSTR` behaves same way. If you are comfortable with Oracle SQL, you can relate to it.
SQL Fiddle link here where both cases are shown-
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e00a4a/17

Answer (score 0):

As the information from [Informatica Docs](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/substr.html) Substring need 3 Argument, one of them is `start` and the docs said if the start position is 0, SUBSTR searches from the first character in the string, and if the start position is a positive number, SUBSTR locates the start position by counting from the beginning of the string.